# Use the deductive method to prove the following propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

a) $$((q → p) ∧  (r → p)) ⇒ ((q ∨ r) → p)$$
b) $$(p → q) ∧  (r → s) ∧ (p ∨ r) ⇒ q ∨ s$$

Someone please solve the first one, and tell me what properties I need to memorize and how to apply them, the second I'll try to do myself by following the tips.

[image]

[rules I need to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gggXt.jpg)

Comment: Could you let me know if my parsing of the first (a), is what you mean, in therms of the left side and right side of the implication?

Comment: @Goun2 I can't quite decipher 1 ... is there a $c$ in there? .. for contradiction? (I am also looking at 11)

Comment: @Goun2 So these are just the rules (though many of them don't have a name ...)... they are stated rather unusually ... so I am not sure how you actually *use* these rules ... do you have an example of a worked out problem?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, I'll send one.

Comment: @Goun2 OK, great!

Comment: @Bram28 https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7I2J.jpg, questions solved by a friend.

Comment: @Goun2  But those are all with the $\Leftrightarrow$ again ... and it is using the equivalence principles I mentioned in my original Answer, rather than any of the rules you posted earlier .. and you can't use the equivalence rules for problems that have a $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @Bram28 My teacher sent a picture of an exercise solved by him, take a look, and here He used the ⇒, https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAsuR.jpg

Comment: @Bram28 another example here using the ⇒, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpxLy.jpg

Comment: @Bram28 Bro, I value your efforts to help me, But if you need to do other things I'll  totally understand.

Comment: @Goun2 That second example is *still* using equivalence rules.  So it is still proving a $\Leftrightarrow$ rather than just a $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @Goun2 Yeah, I hate to do this to you, but I am really a bit stuck here  without having an example of how to prove $\Rightarrow$ claims, especially given the rather unusual rules your teacher gave you.  But, I'll do what I suggested in an earlier comment: transform the left side so it becomes a conjunction, where one of the conjuncts is the right hand side. Give me a few minutes ...

Comment: @Bram28 I think now I got what You wanted, I asked someone to give me a picture of the answers of these 2 questions, Just because of your interest in helping me I'll mark this as solved, But now with the resolutions of the quetions, if you can make me understand this, I'll be forever thankful to you. img - i.stack.imgur.com/hrNoW.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrNoW.jpg

Comment: @Goun2 Whoever did these problems did something highly irregular: note that the person treated the $\Rightarrow$ as if it were a $\rightarrow$. But there is a big difference between them: the $\rightarrow$ is a logic symbol that you can use to create logic statements. BUt the $\Rightarrow$ is a *meta-logical* symbol: it is used to make claims *about* logic statements. THus, for example, I can say $P \rightarrow Q$ to say something like 'If John is happy, then Mary is happy too'. But it is certainly *not* true that $P \Rightarrow Q$, because $Q$ is not logically implied by $P$.

Comment: BUt note that in the answers you just posted, the person writing this trated the $\Rightarrow$ as if it were a $\rightarrow$, and applied the Implcation equivalence to the $\Rightarrow$. NOw, as it so happens, things work out ok in this case, because $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ if and only if $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ is a tautology, and the latter is what is shown in the answer, but  you really shouldn't be doing this!

Comment: Anyway, for these answers, I think you should be able to identify which equivalence principle was each in each step ... for most of the steps. FOr both answers, the first step was Implication, and the second step was DeMorgan ... can you recognize some of the others? THat is actually a really good exercise to get to know these principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have conditionals, it is typically a good idea to rewrite them using the following equivalence:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

Because after rewriting your conditionals, you are typically left with $\land$, $\lor$, and $\neg$, and you have *lots* of equivalence principles for those!

Here is a short list of useful properties you should definitely know. And remember that they go both ways, i.e. you can go from left to right, bt also from right to left (especially for Distribution people forget that you can go the other way, which we might call 'Reverse Distribution'):

**Double Negation**

$\neg \neg P \Leftrightarrow P$

**Commutation**

$P \land Q \Leftrightarrow Q \land P$

$P \lor Q \Leftrightarrow Q \lor P$

**Association**

$P \land (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \land R$

$P \lor (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \lor R$

**DeMorgan**

$\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$

$\neg(P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$

**Distribution**

$P \land (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

$P \lor (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

With these, you can solve many problems already, including your a):

$$(q \rightarrow p) \land (r \rightarrow p) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$(\neg q \lor p) \land (\neg r \lor p) \Leftrightarrow \text{ ((reversed) Distribution)}$$

$$(\neg q \land \neg r) \lor p \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\neg (q \lor r) \lor p \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$(q \lor r) \rightarrow p$$

So, since we have now shown that $(q \rightarrow p) \land (r \rightarrow p) \Leftrightarrow (q \lor r) \rightarrow p$, we can conclude that $(q \rightarrow p) \land (r \rightarrow p) \Rightarrow (q \lor r) \rightarrow p$

Your b) is unfortunately not an equivalence, so we'll have to do the next best thing:

$$(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) \land (p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Consensus)}$$

$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor s) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Consensus)}$$

$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor s) \land (q \lor s)$$

So, since we have now shown that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) \land (p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow (\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor s) \land (q \lor s)$, and since $q \lor s$ is one of the conjunctions of $(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor s) \land (q \lor s)$, it follows that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) \land (p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow q \lor s$

Here, I used a pretty powerful equivalence principle called Consensus:

**Consensus**

$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R) \land (P \lor R)$

$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R)$

Comment: The asker has asked for a proof, using  the **deductive method.** This requires proving, via a deductive proof $\rightarrow$, and proving, via a deductive proof $\leftarrow$.

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry, I wrote the quetions wrong.

Comment: Now it's correct, the first and the second has a ⇒ instead of a ⇔. But You don't need to edit your answer, I'll try to do them by your explanations, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Goun2 So are you supposed to use the kinds of equivalence principles I used in my answer?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, That's right.

Comment: @Goun2 If it is just a $\Rightarrow$, then using equivalence principles aren't really going to work, since they establish $\Leftrightarrow$ instead of $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @Goun2 One way you *can* use equivalence principles to establish a $\Rightarrow$ is to apply the equivalence principles on the left side until you get a statement of the form $RHS \land ...$ where $RHS$ is the right hand side. So, you can try to change the left-hand side using the equivalences to $(q \lor s) \land ...$, and then point to that and say 'now it's obvious that the right side is implied.  Are you allowed to do that?  Were you told how you are supposed to prove $\Rightarrow$ claims?

Comment: @Bram28 I'll provide a picture of the problems I need to solve, I'm very confused.

Comment: @Goun2 Yes, a picture will help!  Don;t worry you are confused!  It's just that there are several different methods to 'prove' things in logic, and we are just trying to establish what method you were supposed to use, and I think you just haven;t seen all those different methods, so this is confusing for you, I understand.

Comment: @amWhy OK, I'll try!

Comment: @Bram28 ${}{}{}{}$ :-)

Comment: @Bram28 I added a picture of the exercises I need to solve, I need to solve them by using the deductive method.

Comment: @Goun2 OK, thanks.  'deductive method' is still rather ambiguous though": *all* methods in logic are deductive!  Are you provided with an example maybe?  Or can you send me a pic of the page before it that maybe lists the principles or rules you are supposed to use?

Comment: @Goun2  And also: I probably confused you more than I helped initially ...so my apologies!  And don't worry, I'll fix this! I know logic! :)

Comment: @Bram28 I'll need to use these rules, Simplification,Addition,Modus Ponens Modus Tollens, disjunctive syllogism, Reduction to the Absurd, Exportation and Importation.

Comment: @Goun2  Never heard of Importation .. can you explain that one?  Also, some of the other rules are defined differently by different books ... are you sure you don't have a nice one or two pages with all the rules?  Maybe in the appendix?  If you are using a book, what is the title?

Comment: @Bram28 You don't need to apologize, helps are always appreciated, I'm glad because you are trying to help me and I value your will.

Comment: @Bram28 I don't have a book, my teacher only writes, I'll provide a picture.